# How to set a starting point when the parenting of objects should start

Tags: animation

How can i set a starting point when a object start´s it parenting relation with an object . 
Imagine a scenario where a hand takes a glass and lifts it of a table .
to make this in blender i want that the hand that goes down, not being locked to an empty in the glass, but when the hand touchess the glass and lifts the glass i want that in that moment the parent relation with the glass starts and the hand will then smoothly lift the class. 
Is there a way to set when the parenting begins so that it begins at the point i my self decide .[image]

Comment: You can use a 'copy location' constraint and use the 'influence' parameter to activate of deactivate it

Answer (score 1):

**Child of constraint**

[image]

---

It behaves in a similar fashion to parent.  You can move the [child] or the target parent. By having a total of two constraints, one for each hand, you could move the glass from hand to hand.  Set keyframes to control start and 
finish of control.  Of course employing paths will bring smooth motion.

Comment: I think "copy location" is better, because child of shifts the child depending on the parent location (or I missed something)

Comment: You missed something.  Clarity will come for you when you use all the features of the panel.  Documentation .... https://www.blender.org/manual/rigging/constraints/relationship/child_of.html

Comment: ok, you are right. It was because I used it at the target level and not at the bone level. Thanks atomicbezierslinger

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all who answered, i used the copy location as a solution.
One empty was in the middle of the glass and the emptys child was where the hand was supposed to be .
i made the hand child for the child of the main empty .
then i just locked ( by pressing i on the influence bar ) and by locking the influence set the frame where i wantted the influence start to happen .

Comment: Suggestion. Please mark your own proposed answer as the final answer.  This will make it instantaneously clear to people that the question has an accepted answer, even without reading detail.  No reading time wasted.  Of course lemon could still convert his comment to an answer and receive credit.  You and lemon can negotiate that.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger, I think this is not necessary, but thanks.

Comment: i tryed to findt a " case closed " button, but did not findt it . where is it .